# Invoicing button missing

Tags: civicontribute, invoice, button

I'm are trying to get the "Tax and Invoicing"(civicontribute) te work. I used [these](https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/4.6/contributions/invoicing/).

It works fine when I select one or more contributions and use the action pull down. But opening the details of an specific contribution doesn't show the Print Invoice of E-mail invoice button, as shown in CiviCRM Userguide:
[image]

I use Civicrm 4.6.22 and 4.7.11 and php 5.6.

Any ideas?

Comment: Thank you but that doesn't solve the issue.

Comment: @user5072  Did you found the cause for the problem? I am facing the same issue

Comment: Same problem here. Would also be very interested in knowing whether the issue has been solved now...? @user5072!?

Answer (score 1):

Try clearing your caches: administer -> system settings -> Cleanup Caches and Update Paths;

Comment: I am having the same issue and cleaning up caches and updating paths didn't help.